# Clipping Raster Object with Polygon Object in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, polygon, clip, error-000628

I have about 400 rasters that I want to clip each of them based on a polygon object.

The code I tried to use is the following:

```
import arcpy, os
origpath = ur'd:\test'
jpgs = [f for f in os.listdir(origpath) if f.endswith('.jpg') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(origpath,f))]
for jpg in jpgs:
    r = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(origpath,jpg))
    p = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(562879.802,4538631.518),arcpy.Point(583906.505,4538842.192),arcpy.Point(584139.129,4518489.715),arcpy.Point(563054.256,4518279.244)]))
    arcpy.Clip_management(r,p,os.path.join(origpath,'clipped_'+jpg),'#','#','ClippingGeometry')
```

When it runs it produces an error:

```
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter rectangle.
```

I assume that it has to do with the Polygon Object, I have inserted, for the Extent parameter.

The last solution would be to put this one polygon in a feature class and then add this feature class as the extent parameter.

Is there any direct way to use the Polygon Object to clip my rasters?

Answer (score 1):

The help for Clip (management) gives this example:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.Clip_management("c:/data/image.tif","1952602 294196 1953546 296176",
    "c:/data/clip.gdb/clip01", "#", "#", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

It looks like you want to provide the clip extent as a string of 4 numeric values (ordered X-Minimum, Y-Minimum, X-Maximum, Y-Maximum) instead of creating a polygon object.

To preserve your existing code, make the following change:

```
import arcpy, os
origpath = ur'd:\test'
jpgs = [f for f in os.listdir(origpath) if f.endswith('.jpg') and 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(origpath,f))]
for jpg in jpgs:
    r = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(origpath,jpg))
    p = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(562879.802,4538631.518),arcpy.Point(583906.505,4538842.192),arcpy.Point(584139.129,4518489.715),arcpy.Point(563054.256,4518279.244)]))
    extent_p = p.extent
    arcpy.Clip_management(r, '{} {} {} {}'.format(extent_p.XMin, extent_p.YMin, extent_p.XMax, extent_p.YMax), os.path.join(origpath,'clipped_'+jpg),'#','#','ClippingGeometry')
```

Comment: It seems that it passes the error with the extent parameter as you correctly suggested but now it produces a new error: `The clip feature is outside the raster extent. Failed to execute (Clip).` The extents of the polygon and the raster are exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?